# "value" attribute not showing in javascript code. "ValueOf()" only comes up with the intellisense

Tags: javascript

Why am I not getting access to the "value" attribute in this javascript code. "ValueOf()" only comes up with the intellisense..

```
function CheckMessage()
{
    var contactDetails = [];
    var y = document.getElementById('firstName').ValueOf();

}
```

I want the value of the element with id firstName, but it is not giving me that option.

Here is the html:

```
  <form>
     First Name:<br><input type="text" id="firstName"><br>

    <input type="button" value="Preview Message" onclick="CheckMessage()" >
  </form>
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @LightStyle *IntelliSense*, so presumably Visual Studio

Comment: Have you tryed using .value only?

Comment: im using netbeans 7.3

Comment: ok i feel like an idiot but it is working now. still intellisense doesn't show it. Sorry for wasting your time guys. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the fail 
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'ValueOf'

ValueOf() on javascript doesn't exist, is with "v".

to access de text on input try this:

```
 var y = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
```

Comment: `valueOf` is part of ECMAScript and is a method of [Object.prototype](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.4). It is not necessarily supported by host objects (like DOM objects), and even then the returned value is implementation dependent. Also, it doesn't return the type.

Comment: ah, I didn't know, sorry.

Comment: —most browsers in use seem to support it on DOM objects, but the returned value may not be consistent across browsers.